# Adding a text or drawing to the uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have code that adds a text label, a subtitle and the accessory icon like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

// And I see code in the docs for an image:
cell.imageView.image = ...
```

But I want the place where the image goes (on the left) to be a text or lablel (like in Instagram) or a draw circle (like the Apple favorites call screen). How is this done?

Comment: Use a storyboard or xib to design your cell

Comment: is there a way to do it programatically?

Comment: Create custom cell programmatically: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/ios-programmatically-create-custom-cell.html

Answer (score 4):

**Although with `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` you get `imageView` property on `UITableViewCell` for free and you can use it**, just in case, you want to have fine control on placement of `imageView` and labels on cell, you need to go for **custom `UITableViewCell`**. Here are the steps on how to achieve this:

**Step 1 :** Create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass say `MyCustomCell`.

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
```

**Step 2 :** Implement `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method in `MyCustomCell.m` and add any custom view to cell content view.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)iStyle reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)iReuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:iStyle reuseIdentifier:iReuseIdentifier])) {
         MyView *myCustomView = [[MyView alloc] init];
         myCustomView.frame = CGRectMake(6.0f, 6.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
         [self.contentView addSubview:myCustomView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**Step 3 :** Implement `layoutSubviews` method to have fine control on your cell content subviews.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(6.0f, 6.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    GFloat textLabelXPosition = self.imageView.frame.origin.x + self.imageView.frame.size.width + 10;
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(textLabelXPosition, 0.0, contentRect.size.width - textLabelXPosition, contentRect.size.height);
}
```

**Step 4 :** Finally use `MyCustomCell` instance in you table view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

create an imageView `image`, and then add following lines to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
CGRect newFrame;
newFrame.origin.x = self.accessoryView.frame.origin.x;
newFrame.origin.y = self.accessoryView.frame.origin.y;

self.image.frame= newFrame;
```

this will give you the access to coordinates of accessory view. Now override with your text/ label.
create A label in your xib - `yourLabel`

```
self.yourLabel.frame= newFrame;
```